# Factoring out expressions in linq queries

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Let's say I have the following Linq2Entities query for some service method:

```
public IQueryable<CustomerProjection>()
{
    return
        from i in this.DbContext.Customers
        select new CustomerProjection()
        {
            Reference = new EntityReference()
            {
                Id = i.Id,
                Name = i.Name
            }
        }
}
```

All my model entities, including Customer, all support the following interface:

```
interface INamedEntity
{
    String Name { get; set; }
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

so that in principle I'm tempted to do some refactoring:

```
public IQueryable<CustomerProjection>()
{
    return
        from i in this.DbContext.Customers
        select new CustomerProjection()
        {
            // I want something something like this:
            Reference = GetReference(i)
        }
}
```

obviously I can't naivly define GetReference this way:

```
public EntityReference GetReference<E>(E i)
    where E : INamedEntity
{
    return new EntityReference()
    {
        Id = i.Id,
        Name = i.Name,
    };
}
```

What I need to factor out is the logic to create an expression for a query, not an EntityReference directly. So let's define it this way:

```
public Expression<Func<INamedEntity, EntityReference>> GetReferenceExpression()
    where E : INamedEntity
{
    return i => new EntityReference()
    {
        Id = i.Id,
        Name = i.Name,
    };
}
```

This correctly factors the logic away. However, I can't use it in the main query:

```
public IQueryable<CustomerProjection>()
{
    return
        from i in this.DbContext.Customers
        select new CustomerProjection()
        {
            // Something like "Invoke" doesn't exist!
            Reference = GetReferenceExpression().Invoke(i)
        }
}
```

I need something like this "Invoke" extension method supported by Linq2Entities to help me actually use my factored-out logic.

Note that this is an example scenario with reduced complexity. I understand that factoring in this simple instance isn't really necessary, but I had cases more complex where I wish I could do something like that.

Also, there is a second, related scenario in which one not only wants to use the factored-out code in more than one query, but evaluate it directly:

```
GetReferenceExpression().Compile()(myEntity);
```

This is especially interesting if the factored-out code is a predicate for a filter.

So my question is:

1. Does Linq2Entities support something like this? If so, how?
2. Is there another linq provider independent way of factoring out expressions?

Comment: I don't understand your update. You can still filter on the "proper enties" `where x.Entity.Property1 == value`

Comment: @Aducci I reverted the update - I'd accept the answer if it didn't fail to work for me. I think you're approach is generally a good solution for this kind of problem and I should post another question if I want to get a different one.

Comment: Note to myself and others: I need to check out linqkit, a linq to entities and linq to sql helper library that appears to address this issue - it even has an extension method called "Invoke" for this pupose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a proxy LINQ provider that sits in front of EF's LINQ provider. You can do any rewrite that you want in that place.

I have done this. It is a lot of work but it can certainly be done. You could, for example, make your provider rewrite this:

```
Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>> someFilter = e => e.SomeProperty == 1234;
...
from e in db.Entities
where MyCustomLINQProvider.CallExpression(someFilter, e)
select e
```

to this:

```
from e in db.Entities
where e.SomeProperty == 1234
select e
```

which is acceptable for EF's LINQ provider. `MyCustomLINQProvider.CallExpression` would be a helper that is never called at runtime. It is just there as a marker for your rewriting engine to inline the given expression. Without that helper the code would not compile.

To do this you'd need to implement a custom `IQueryable`. This interface is defined as:

```
public interface IQueryable : IEnumerable
{
    Type ElementType { get; }
    Expression Expression { get; }
    IQueryProvider Provider { get; }
}

public interface IQueryProvider
{
    IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression);
    IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression);
    object Execute(Expression expression);
    TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression);
}
```

In `IQueryProvider.Execute` you perform the rewriting and relay the query to EF's `IQueryProvider`.

---

You could make `MyCustomLINQProvider.CallExpression` an extension so it's less awkward to use:

```
static bool Call<TTarget, TArg0>(
  this Expression<Func<TArg0, TReturn>> target, TArg0 arg0) {
 throw new NotSupportedException("cannot call this statically");
}
...
where someFilter.Call(e) //looks almost like a func
```

You need a layer above EF to abstract away the LINQ provider:

```
ObjectContext objectContext;
IQueryable<T> Query<T>() {
 return new MyCustomQueryable<T>(objectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>());
}
```

So don't ask EF for a query, ask your code so that you can be handed a proxy.

In your expression rewriter, you don't have to do a lot. You look for the right pattern and just replace the predicate ParameterExpression with whatever was passed as an argument to `Call`. Here's a sketch:

```
protected virtual Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
{
    if (IsCall(node)) {
     var expressionToInline = GetExpressionToInline(node.Arguments[0]);
     var arg0 = node.Arguments[1];
     var parameter = expressionToInline.Parameters[0];
     var predicateExpression = ReplaceExpression(original: expressionToInline.Body, toReplace: parameter, replaceWith: arg0);
     return predicateExpression;
    }

    return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
}
```

There's sample code for `ReplaceExpression` available on the web.

Comment: This is sort of what I was hoping for, except for the "a lot of work" bit. I was just writing another question to get an answer like this, but I think I now just drop it...

Comment: @John feel free to ask me follow up questions. I do not always write the full answer that I have in mind because I do not know what specifically interests an OP and whether he's going to appreciate it. Is this work or free-time for you? If it's free time, do it by all means. Writing an expression rewriter is a lot of fun :) Bends your mind a bit and makes you better.

Comment: It's work and writing a linq provider wouldn't be economical for me, although I'm self-employed and don't always do the most economical thing. I played around with linq-providers and do have a basic understanding of what's going on. I was hoping that, in this case, there was already something in place that I wasn't aware of. For example, there could have been an extension method "Invoke" in some secret namespace, the CallExpression of which EF would interpret as such an evaluation. It's probably more realistic to hack EF and get the patch approved.

Comment: I have sketched how you would do this. It is much less work than I thought. I did not leave out a lot.

Comment: Can't find this ReplaceExpression thing with google.

Comment: Yeah it's not a standard thing. Everyone writes their own. Here's one: https://gist.github.com/SamWM/2029839 (search for ReplaceVisitor). All it does is replace one expression by another. You need to replace the lambda parameter in the lambda's body by the actual parameter value because EF can't apply the lambda itself. You go from `(e => e.SomeProperty == 1234)(someE)` to `someE.SomeProperty == 1234`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

**Interfaces:**

```
public interface IReference
{
  int ID { get; }
  string Name { get; }
}
```

**Concrete classes that implement the interfaces**

```
public class Reference : IReference
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ReferenceAndEntity<T>
{
  public Reference Reference { get; set; }
  public T Entity { get; set }
}
```

**IQueryable**

```
public static IQueryable<ReferenceAndEntity<T>> GetReferenceAndEntityQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> set) where T: class, IReference
{
  var query = from x in set
              select new ReferenceAndEntity<T>()
              {
                Reference = new Reference()
                {
                  ID = x.ID,
                  Name = x.Name
                },
                Entity = x
              };
  return query;
}
```

**Usage**

```
using(DbContext context = new Context())
{
  var query = from x in GetReferenceAndEntityQuery(context.dataSet)
              select new
              {
                Reference = x.Reference,
                EntityProperty1 = x.Entity.Property1,
              };
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer the way I posed my question, but only because I reduced the example case too much. I will make the example more realistic so that a solution like this no longer applies.

Comment: I thought about it a bit more and the approach would work in more cases than I thought. I can't get it to work though. EF is telling me: "Unable to cast the type 'MonkeyBusters.MonkeyManage.Web.Models.Customer' to type 'MonkeyBusters.MonkeyManage.Web.Models.INamedEntity'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types." (INamedEntity is what you called IReference) I didn't try exactly what you did though: I needed GetReferenceAndEntityQuery to take arbitrary IQuerable<T>s instead of DbSet<T>s. I don't think Entity Framework likes this.

Comment: @John, I removed the extra interface, make sure you are returning a concrete class (not an interface). Changing from DbSet to IQueryable is fine. If you are still encountering an error, post your code